# trigger cron job from web application

Tags: python, web-server, cron, servo

I would like to improve on my project by using cron jobs. 
Currently, i have a web application that allows me to control servos. However I would like to add another function on the web application where i can set the cron job to execute a script that would control the servos automatically. meaning that i can click on a button on the web specifying that i'm not at home or something and that would tell cron job to take over.

Any idea how can i do this? A link or tutorial would be good too. :)

Comment: The way you are using "cron" does not make sense to me. cron is for adding jobs that are scheduled. But you imply you want immediate action when the button is pressed.
Just have cron execute runmotors.py once an hour and your web server execute runmotors.py when you click a button.

Comment: hi @rob . no as in, when i click that "cron start" button, i will set the cron to start doing things, say twice per day. the purpose here is when i'm not at home to do the controlling, the task can still be done.

Comment: so is your question "how do I add a job to cron programmatically" ?

Comment: there is a great discussion about this on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job

Comment: wow. thanks @rob. yeah, i think that's a better phrase for the question :) sorry, i'm quite new to this and havent try cron yet.

Answer (score 3):

Is it just me or does the thought of allowing a web application to edit cron jobs give you the willies.

Here is how I would go about it: Setup a cron job to **always** run at the frequency you desire. Make it run the script you want. In the script the first thing you do is read a small settings file which tells it whether to continue or not, for instance

```
run=false
```

Now when you want the job to actually run you make your web application edit the settings file setting `run=true` and the next time the cron job is run the script will run in its entirety.

Just make sure you use absolute paths throughout.

Comment: +1 sounds simple enough but what do you mean by "small settings file"? can you provide more details on this? :)

Comment: The default choice is a text file containing simply the single line ``run=false``. However depending upon the programming language being used by the web application the settings file could be a script itself for instance a python script that simply contains ``run = False`` and is imported by the application. This avoids having to open, read content and close the file but has its own set of pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into GO based groundcontrol daemon at https://github.com/jondot/groundcontrol? It is very light on CPU resource and has a very simple control UI with various buttons for executing simple bash commands or complex scripts.

In your case, let's say you have a cronjob entry to allow a script named, `servos.sh` run every 30 minutes.

```
crontab -l
*/30 * * * * /scripts/servos.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If you want conditional on/off for this cron job, then you can execute `sed` based command to enable/disable specific cronjob, and assign these commands to ON/OFF buttons in groundcontrol app.

Relevant portion of `/etc/groundcontrol.json` will look like this. Check groundcontrol [documentation](https://github.com/jondot/groundcontrol) for installing daemon and editing config file.

```
"controls" : {
    "servos_cron": {
      "on" : "crontab -l | sed '/servos/s/^#//' | crontab -",
      "off" : "crontab -l | sed '/^\*.*servos/s/^/#/' | crontab -"
    }
  }
```

PS: Upon clicking `off` button in groundcontrol UI, sed command will place "#" character at the beginning of running servos cronjob entry, **given it begins with asterix**. If your cron entry has different parameter at the beginning, edit `off` command accordingly.

Once you restart groundcontrol, you will get nice UI at localhost:4571 (port can be changed) allowing you to manage servos cron by pressing a button!

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: +1 hmm definitely worth trying when i'm not in rush to achieve it, cos i know nothing about json and i'm using python and cherrypy currently.

Comment: You do not need to know json scripting for this. Groundcontrol documentation is all you need. Here is my `/etc/groundcontrol.json` file for running groundcontrol as a daemon: http://pastebin.com/7w07CuXh Script is pretty much self-explanatory, and you can add/remove commands as per you need. Unlike other scripting, I doubt if json file respects comment character "#", and so I'd no comment lines within script. PS: I am not the groundcontrol owner but simply love that app!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered having `cron` always run your job and then have a flag that the script that `cron` starts checks to see if the script should execute or not.

This flag could be the presence of a file.  If the file exists (easily checked in a shell script) the script would just exit.

Now all your web page needs to do is create the file if you want the script disabled and delete the file if you want the script to run.

Here's some python code to create and delete the flag file.

To create:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

def touch(fname, times=None):
    with file(fname, 'a'):
        os.utime(fname, times)

# Create file called /tmp/flag_file
touch("/tmp/flag_file")
```

To delete:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

myfile="/tmp/flag_file"

## if file exists, delete it ##
if os.path.isfile(myfile):
    os.remove(myfile)
else:    ## Show an error ##
    print("Error: %s file not found" % myfile)
```

Comment: +1 but i have no idea how to do that. O_o i'm currently running a python script that starts cherrypy web server at port 8080

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have understood your question and comments, what you are actually asking for is a way to access e.g. the python scripts by HeatfanJohn / edit the configuration file by Abid H. Mujtaba via your webserver.

The way I would to this is use a small PHP File. For this to work, you will need to have PHP installed. The File could look somewhat like this:

```
    <?php
    $path='/var/www/cron_onoff.txt';
    $text=$_GET['arg'];
    shell_exec('echo '.$text.' > '.$path);
    ?>
```

Save it for example as "cron_onoff.php" in your /var/www folder.
Now, on your HTML Website, you add a link to enable, and another to disable:

```
    <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    <a href="cron_onoff.php?arg=on">Turn ON</a><br />
    <a href="cron_onoff.php?arg=off">Turn OFF</a><br />
    </body></html>
```

Now, when you click the first link, the text "on" (without quotes) will be written into the file you specified in the php-script, when you click the second link, the content will be replaces by "off".
Whatever your cronjob runs should now open this file, and check if "on" is written there, otherwise stop executing. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749330/how-to-test-if-string-exists-in-file-with-bash-shell) StackOverflow question on how to do something like this with bash).

Also, if you decide to put the file cron_onoff.txt elsewhere, you might get some trouble with permissions to write. Remember, the active user for scripts executed via Webbrowser is 'www-data', so you have to grant at least some basic permissions. Also, if this doesn't work, your PHP might [not have been configured to allow the execution of shell scripts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php).

Finally, you can, of course, use different commands in the shell_exec-Function.
For example,

```
    shell_exec('python /var/www/script.py');
```

could run one of the scripts provided by HeatfanJohn. Be sure to add the executable flag for the www-data user for the script:
(run in Terminal)

```
  cd /var/www
  sudo chown script.py www-data:www-data
  sudo chmod +x script.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will look into this again. :D